# Initializing PlusClient Android

Tags: android, google-plus

I am trying to initialize PlusClient to add google+ button as

```
PlusClient mPlusClient = new PlusClient(this, this, this)
        .clearScopes()
        .build();
```

as mentioned [here](https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/recommend#initialize_the_plusclient)

But getting error as "Constructor not defined". I am using the latest Google Play Servies library.

Comment: Can you provide some more context for your implementation? You're likely missing a piece somewhere, judging by the error message, but it is difficult to guess where.

Comment: @Joanna You were right I found the mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the solution. I forgot to implement the following interfaces `ConnectionCallbacks` and `OnConnectionFailedListener`